# Add column and list sites in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to add a column to my data.frame and I need to have one site per each row, while now R would just list all my sites in the same row
      I added the new column:

```
mdspoints$sitename <- ('B,E,F,K,R,B,E,F,K,R')
```

and this is what I get

```
         NMDS1       NMDS2            sitename
 1 -0.10675081 -0.31135031 B,E,F,K,R,B,E,F,K,R
 2 -0.06941165 -0.15541436 B,E,F,K,R,B,E,F,K,R
 3  0.16005296 -0.08913313 B,E,F,K,R,B,E,F,K,R
4 -0.14806604  0.23204307 B,E,F,K,R,B,E,F,K,R
5 -0.04930029  0.02153935 B,E,F,K,R,B,E,F,K,R
 6 -0.06342087 -0.07401687 B,E,F,K,R,B,E,F,K,R
```

while what I need is

```
         NMDS1       NMDS2  sitename
 1 -0.10675081 -0.31135031 B
 2 -0.06941165 -0.15541436 E
 3  0.16005296 -0.08913313 F
 4 -0.14806604  0.23204307 K
 5 -0.04930029  0.02153935 R
 6 -0.06342087 -0.07401687 B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct a vector, not just a single string, something like:

```
mdspoints$sitename<-c('B','E','F','K','R','B','E','F','K',R')
```

the c() denotes a vector.